# Adobe AE Motion files in IOS views

Tags: ios, motion, dvd, after-effects

Does anyone have any suggestions on not very painful ways to add already created Motion files as background animation clips in IOS projects.  Any tools, that can help?

TIA.

Comment: How about rendering an MP4 video from it?

Comment: @Till I do not have the AE.  Are there opensource, freeware tools that can render an mp4?  As I understand in IOS the animation requires sequence of images.  Is there a way to create sequence of images directly from the motion file?

Comment: Those series of single image files will easily hog A LOT of memory.